# in mysql trigger.. how to use insert into and update query

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, insert-update

I have a product_price_log table. I updated where ever new price is updated in product_price
table.

I am using a trigger:

```
drop trigger if exists product_update; 

delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER product_update
BEFORE update ON w3xab_virtuemart_product_prices
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE virtuemart_product_id int;
DECLARE old_product_price decimal(15,5) default 0;
DECLARE new_product_price decimal(15,5) default 0;
DECLARE price_update_date DATE;

IF (new.product_price <> old.product_price)
THEN 

INSERT into product_price_log
(virtuemart_product_id,old_product_price, new_product_price,  price_update_date)
VALUES (new.virtuemart_product_id, old.product_price, new.product_price, CURDATE())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
old_product_price = VALUES(old.product_price),
new_product_price = VALUES(new.product_price),
price_update_date = CURDATE();


END IF;
    END$$
    delimiter ;
```

now no error..but update not working when i try to update price... only insert is working

i set **virtuemart_product_id** is primay key
i dont know whats going i m totally stuck at this point... cant understand why not updating..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do `VALUES(CURDATE())` since it isn't actually a column name.
Try just `price_update_date=CURDATE()`

Comment: done... just remove keyword VALUES ....VALUES(old.product_price) instead simple old_product_price = old.product_price, and its now working